# Different ways of making read public write private variables in swift?

Tags: swift, variables, properties, private

I've completed a online course that taught us to write properties of classes as:

```
class bar {
     private var _foo:Int

     var foo {
         return _foo
     }     
}
```

Since then i've seen

```
class bar {
     private (set) var foo:Int 
}
```

Is there any difference between these two ways of writing things, and which would be best practise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second option is simpler and clearer and it has the added benefit of still being able to add `get`, `set`, `willSet`, and `didSet` blocks on the property while still having clearly defined scope on the getter and setter. Of course you can still add those to the private property but I think the code starts to get less readable.

Also note that the first option is a public read-only computed property making use of a private stored property.

The second option can be either a computed or stored property.